# How can I load another level in unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to make a 5-level game by unity, but I don't know how to do it. How can I load the upper level when the loaded level completed? And how can I add a level to build settings? And how can I make separated levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In build settings there's a button with the text "Add Current" click on it and the open scene will be added to your build... also you can drag and drop all your scenes in the same screen...a level can be considered as a Scene, so in order to have 5 levels you need to create  5  scenes..and to load a new level you do it via script:

```
public static function LoadLevel(index: int): void;
public static function LoadLevel(name: string): void;
```